# Executing commands in a particular terminal tab when terminal restarts

Tags: macos

When I use terminal on OSX, I normally have console terminal open with a number of different tabs. In one of those tabs I have a localhost server and in another tab I have a different server. I have saved this window configuration as a windows group that is reopened when I restart terminal, say upon rebooting.

When I restart terminal, I want the two tabs with servers in them to restart the servers.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366171/128890) by @jmh in Ask Different:

Go to Preferences under the Terminal menu and a panel opens.  Click on the profiles icon in the top left of the panel and this opens a new panel with options like Text, Windows, Tab, Shell etc across the top.  Choose the Shell option and in the Startup section, check `Run Command` and enter your command into the empty box.